# PHP Form Dropdown List from Array

Tags: php, form-submit

I have  PHP page where it collects fileames from folder and populates array then that array is used to create dropdown list. But I want to submit the value that selected and display and thats where I stop. Please help.
Thanks in advance.

```
<?php
// open this directory    
$myDirectory = opendir("Media/MP3_Para");

// get each entry
while($entryName = readdir($myDirectory)) {
$dirArray[] = $entryName;
}

 // close directory     
closedir($myDirectory);

//  count elements in array
$indexCount = count($dirArray);

 // sort 'em     

sort($dirArray);

// create dropdown list 
echo "<form method='POST'  action='1.php' > " ;
echo "Change Selection : " ;

echo "<select name='my_select'>"  ;

foreach($dirArray AS $index) {  

// remove .  or .. from list
if (substr("$index", 0, 1) != ".") {
$titlname1=$index ;
$name1=substr($titlname1,0,-4) ;
$titlname1=$name1 ; 

echo '<option value="'.$index.'">'.$titlname1.'</option>' ;
            }
            } 
echo '</select>';

echo "<input type='submit' class='NavLinks' " ;

echo "</form>" ;

echo my_select ;
 ?>

</body>
```

Comment: You have a few issues in your code. The input is missing the closing `>` and `echo my_select ;` should either be a string or a variable. Not that it will fix everything, but it would be useful to know what you're trying to do with that one echo statement

Comment: Thanks for the second pair of eyes. I just want to display what value is selected so I can grab that value and pass it to next page.

Comment: If you just want (I'm guessing from the question) to display elsewhere on the same page what value is selected from the dropdown, you need to either use javascript to pull and display that value when another option is selected, or you need to have the form's action set to the same page and have logic at the top to pull the selection from POST/GET and use that to display the data.

Comment: Can you please give me an example as to how would I pass the value to another php page.. I would like to know what variable to pass and how. Thanks for helping a complete noob.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the right direction. I got it working.